# create monochrome bitmap file from byte array whose width should be divisible by 8

Tags: android, xamarin

I need monochrome bitmap file whose width is divisible by 8. Its basic requirement to print image. I am getting byte[] as input and need to create string of bits which I can pass to printer. following is the code I am using but its printing only vertical lines. Can any one help me to create such monochrome file thru code

```
private Android.Graphics.Bitmap ConvertArgbToOneColor(Android.Graphics.Bitmap bmpOriginal, int width, int height)
    {
        Android.Graphics.Bitmap bwBitmap = bmpOriginal;
        float[] hsv = new float[3];
        for (int col = 0; col < bmpOriginal.Width; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < bmpOriginal.Height; row++)
            {
                //   Android.Graphics.Color.ColorToHSV( bmpOriginal.GetPixel(col, row), hsv);
                Android.Graphics.Color.ColorToHSV(Android.Graphics.Color.HSVToColor(bmpOriginal.GetPixel(col, row), hsv), hsv);
                if (hsv[2] > 0.5f)
                {
                    bwBitmap.SetPixel(col, row, Android.Graphics.Color.White);// 0xffffffff);
                }
                else
                {
                    bwBitmap.SetPixel(col, row, Android.Graphics.Color.Black); // 0xff000000);
                }
            }
        }
        return bwBitmap;
    }

public string GetPrintCommand(string FileName, byte[] imageBytes)
    {
        Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        Android.Graphics.Bitmap bmpMonochrome = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(128,128,   Android.Graphics.Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
        Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas = new Android.Graphics.Canvas(bmpMonochrome);
        Android.Graphics.ColorMatrix ma = new Android.Graphics.ColorMatrix();
        ma.SetSaturation(0);
        Android.Graphics.Paint paint = new Android.Graphics.Paint();
        paint.SetColorFilter(new Android.Graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter(ma));
        canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);

        // Convert the file with black and white format
        bmpMonochrome = ConvertArgbToOneColor(bmpMonochrome, 128, 128);

        //create byte array for monochrome image
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.Allocate(bmpMonochrome.ByteCount);
        bmpMonochrome.CopyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
        buffer.Rewind();

        IntPtr classHandle = JNIEnv.FindClass("java/nio/ByteBuffer");
        IntPtr methodId = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(classHandle, "array", "()[B");
        IntPtr resultHandle = JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod(buffer.Handle, methodId);
        byte[] m_imageArray = JNIEnv.GetArray<byte>(resultHandle);

        string BinaryImage = "";
        BinaryImage = BitConverter.ToString(m_imageArray).Replace("-", "");

        string s = string.Format("~DG{0}.GRF,{1},{2},{3}", FileName, bmpMonochrome.ByteCount, bmpMonochrome.RowBytes, BinaryImage);
        JNIEnv.DeleteLocalRef(resultHandle);
        return s;

    }
```

Comment: `am getting byte[] as input`. What do the bytes contain? Or what is your input?

Comment: @greenapps 
 
The input is byte array of image in .png format.